# facing problems while exporting MS word documents using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ms-word

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        @page {
            mso-page-orientation: portrait;
            size: 21cm 29.7cm;
            margin: 1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm;
        }

        @page Section1 {
            mso-header-margin: .5in;
            mso-footer-margin: .5in;
            mso-header: h1;
            mso-footer: f1;
        }

        div.Section1 {
            page: Section1;
        }

        table#hrdftrtbl {
            margin: 0in 0in 0in 15in;
            width: 1px;
            height: 1px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        p.MsoFooter,
        li.MsoFooter,
        div.MsoFooter {
            margin: 0in;
            margin-bottom: .0001pt;
            mso-pagination: widow-orphan;
            tab-stops: center 3.0in right 6.0in;
            font-size: 12.0pt;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>


    <div class="Section1">
        <table id='hrdftrtbl' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style='mso-element:header' id=h1>
                        <!-- HEADER-tags -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>images/images.jpg" width="100"
                                                height="100" alt="">
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <p><b></b>Bangladesh
                                                Agricultural Research Council</p>
                                            <p>Digital Archive</p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <!-- end HEADER-tags -->
                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style='mso-element:footer' id=f1>
                        <div class="row">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <span style='position:relative;z-index:-1'>
                                            <!-- FOOTER-tags -->
                                            Develop and Maintain by Computer & GIS Unit
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <p class="MsoFooter" style="text-align: right;">
                                            <span style='mso-tab-count:2'></span>
                                            Page
                                            <span style='mso-field-code: PAGE; text-align: right;'></span>
                                        </p>
                                    </td>
                                    <!-- end FOOTER-tags -->
                                    </span>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <pre>
<!-- text -->
    </pre>
</body>

</html>
```

When I was exporting a Word file using CodeIgniter 3, I noticed some unnecessary space and an icon between the header and main text content, as shown in the this image.
[image]
Although my code successfully removed the redundant space after the first page, the icon remained. Despite multiple attempts to fix the issues, I was unable to resolve them. To provide a better understanding of the problem, I have included the relevant code details below. Apart from these coding in controller I write

```
(header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; 
filename=\"mydocument_name.doc\"");
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: A .doc file is not a HTML file. Giving it a .doc extension when downloaded doesn't change that fact. I'm surprised Word doesn't protest about this. Anyway Word doesn't necessarily interpret HTML the same way a browser does. You may need to do some experimentation.

Comment: if you know, give me some suggestions

Comment: If I did, I would have said already. I just know that, in general, the html engine in word isn't the same standards as in a browser